# change Bootstrap Mobile Menu to on hover not on click

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I been working with Bootstrap 3 to create a mobile view, when I work with a menu button  in mobile view I figured that it collapse and expand depending on click on the menu button, but now while in landing page customer need to change it to on hover to can see content behind without have to toggle click 
 here the HTML code:-

```
   <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed btn-mobile" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div id="test">
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right menu-mobile">

                <li class="scroll active dropdown homeslider">
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")#homeslider" onclick="$('.scroll').removeClass('active');" class="dropbtn">@Resource.home</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I figure that the `data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"` which is the id that used in menu and button to allow toggle show and hide I try to change this behavior with CSS and jquery but still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use jquery [Hover](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) function. I did a little [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3f7ohe4j/8/) to show you how you could do it.

```
$(".navbar-toggle").hover(function(){

$("#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1").collapse("show");
},
function(){
    $("#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1").collapse("hide");
});
```